# In RNetLogo how do I export a list of agentset details without overwriting the list each time?

Tags: r, list, loops, netlogo

I have a model in NetLogo where agents (turtles) move around a landscape and produce other agents (eggs) at a set rate. The latter don't move. My aim is to collect the the coordinates of eggs and measure things like nearest neighbour distance.

In RNetLogo I have some code to do this:

```
NLCommand("setup")
NLDoCommandWhile("day < 10",  "go")
eggcoords <- list()
eggcoords <- NLGetAgentSet(c("who","xcor","ycor"), "eggs")
```

The problem is that the model slows to a crawl as the number of eggs increases. One solution to this is to kill off the eggs at the end of the day but store their details in a list that I can update each day without overwriting anything. And that's where I'm stuck.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your *day* is constant number of ticks (say 24), you could do something like this:

1. Create `end-of-day` procedure in your NetLogo model where you clear the eggs.
2. Then call your model like this:

   ```
   turtles <- list()

   NLCommand("setup")

   # run for 10 days:
   for (day in 1:10) {
     NLCommand("repeat 24 [go]")
     agent_set <- NLGetAgentSet(c("who", "xcor", "ycor", 
                                  "min [ distance myself ] of other turtles"),
                               "turtles")
     names(agent_set) <- c("who", "xcor", "ycor", "nnd")
     agent_set$day = day
     turtles[[day]] <- agent_set
     NLCommand("end-of-day")
   }
   ```

Note:

1. In the `for` loop `go` is executed 24 times with one `NLCommand` call
2. You can use any NetLogo reporter in `agent.var` argument to `NLGetAgentSet` so you can calculate the nearest neighbour distance on the fly
   with `min [ distance myself ] of other turtles`.
3. The result (`turtles`) is a list of data frames. 
   You can bind them to one data frame with `df_turtles <- do.call(rbind, turtles)`

Comment: Thanks! That really speeds up the model and does exactly what I want. I do the spatial stats afterwards with the package spatstat
`dist <- nndist(x,y) ,
mean(dist)`. I was wondering could I include an if statement at the `agent_set` line to avoid the problem of getting an error if no eggs are produced?

Comment: Yes, you can change the NetLogo reporter by using [`ifelse-value`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/ifelse-value.html). Check if `count other turtles > 0`, for example.